# Convert <m8[ns] to int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using pandas and one of the column is of type `<m8[ns]`. I stored 'days' in it, like 5 days, 3 days, etc.

I want to convert this 'days' column from `<m8[ns]` to `float64`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dtype` you're seeing is the numpy dtype for datetimes, if you just want the days then use  [`dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) to return you the days:

```
df['days'] = df['days'].dt.day
```

See this example:

```
In [124]:
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,1,1), periods=10)})
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 1 columns):
dates    10 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes

In [125]:    
df['dates'].dtype

Out[125]:
dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [126]:
df['day'] = df['dates'].dt.day
df

Out[126]:
       dates  day
0 2016-01-01    1
1 2016-01-02    2
2 2016-01-03    3
3 2016-01-04    4
4 2016-01-05    5
5 2016-01-06    6
6 2016-01-07    7
7 2016-01-08    8
8 2016-01-09    9
9 2016-01-10   10

In [127]:    
df.dtypes

Out[127]:
dates    datetime64[ns]
day               int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Note that the the result of a subtraction of two datetimes is a Timedelta with type '<m8[ns]'. In this case use .dt.days